# Assembly xyz already exists in database

Tags: sql-server

I have restored a database on another server. This database has SQL function that use .NET assemblies, which were installed on the previous server.

What is the easiest way to reinstall there assemblies?

If i just do

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLHelpers
```

I get an error saying: **Assembly SQLHelpers already exists in database**

When i first try to remove by using

```
DROP ASSEMBLY SQLHelpers
```

I get: **DROP ASSEMBLY failed because 'SQLHelpers' is referenced by object**

I could alter all code in all functions, so that it looks like this assembly is not being used anymore, but isn't there a more simple way to update / reinstall / force install this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update an existing assembly you can use `alter assembly SQLHelpers from  ...`

[ALTER ASSEMBLY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186711.aspx)